# A wrong understanding of Permutation and Combination

Tags: permutations, combinations

> Suppose We have 10 different things that we want to distribute to P and Q where P gets 3 and Q gets 7, in how many ways can we do this ? ( order doesnt matter when P or Q  gets them , ie if P gets {a,b,c} then it is same as {b,c,a} )

Now we know the answer will be $${10 \choose 3}\text{ Or } {10 \choose 7}$$
But my basic understanding is this :
The picture that alsways plays out in my mind is this

Row 1 : $\oplus$  $\oplus$ $\oplus$ $\oplus$ $\oplus$ $\oplus$ $\oplus$ $\oplus$ $\oplus$ $\oplus$

Row 2: |_______| |_______________|

```
       P             Q
```

My understanding:

1. First we arrange the different things in row 1 ie in $10!$ ways .
2. Then just bring the row 1 into row 2 , ie whichever balls are above P 's box come into it and the ballss above Q's box go into that box.
3. But even in these small individual boxes there can be many permutations ( which are supposed to be treated as the same , but currently we are not)
4. so we find the no of permutations possible in these small boxes . For P its $3!$ and for Q it is $7!$
5. Now WE DIVIDE our initial arrangements by $3!\cdot 7!$   ( why not subtract ) and get $$\frac{10!}{3! \cdot 7!}$$
   So we got our Answer .

> Now if we have 10 things out of which 3 are same (identical) , and 7 are different  (non identical) ie a total of 8 species of balls, Find the number of ways you can distribute these to P and Q such that P gets 3 and Q gets 7 ?

(I don't know the actual answer but my friend told me that the answer that we were getting from logic is wrong)

By Logic :
Imagine the same picture( the two rows one with balls and other with empty boxes)

1. First we arrange -> $\frac{10!}{3!}$ ( divided by 3! because they are same )
2. Then we try to Find the Arrangements in those little boxes , But this time its not straightforwards , because the same balls can

   Case A : P has 3 identical and Q doesnt have any identical so we get $\frac{3!}{3!} \cdot 7! $

   Case B : P has 2 identical , Q has 1 so $ \frac{3!}{2!} \cdot 7!$

   Case C : P has 1 identical , Q has 2 so $ 3! \cdot \frac{7!}{2!}$

   Case D : P has 0 identical , Q has all 3 so $ 3! \cdot \frac{7!}{3!} $
3. We Add them to get $$\frac{7!3!}{1}+\frac{7!3!}{3}=\frac{7!3!(4)}{3}=8!$$
4. Now we divide the arrangements with no, of repititions ( or whatever ) and we get 
   $$ \frac{10!}{2!8!}={10 \choose 2}$$

Is this Logic Correct  ? Is there a shortcut logic for this ? Also why do we Divide and not subtract the repetition ( in step 5 of question 1 and Step 4 of question 2 )

Comment: Even in the case where there are no identical objects, you're making it way too complicated.  There are $10$ ways to choose the first objects, $9$ ways to choose the second, and $8$ ways to choose the third.  But the order of choosing doesn't matter, so we've counted each choice $3!$ times.  The answer is $$\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8}{3!}=\binom{10}{3}$$

Comment: wdym by 10 ways of choosing the first object ?

Comment: I'm talking about the number of ways to choose the $3$ objects that P gets.  Once we've decided that, there are no further decisions to make; Q gets all the rest.  There are $10$ objects, so $10$ ways to choose the first object for P.

Comment: okay yes if we can decide what P gets then all id done . So P has 10 choices in the beggining. But i cant understand " But the order of choosing doesnt matter so we have counted each choice 3! times " . Because when did you even take the order in your answer that you are taking it out?

Comment: Because choosing item A, then item B, then item C is the same as choosing item C, then item B, then item A, or ....  Each combination of $3$ things can be chosen in $3!$ orders.

Comment: Im sorry i cant understand . But maybe this can clear thigs. If you have a word like 'FREETRAFFIC' and you are supposed to choose three letters how will you do it . is your answer $ \frac{11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9}{2!4!3!}$ where the denominators are 2!  fro R , 3! for F and 4! for E

Comment: According to the site rules, you should not ask new questions in comments.  If you have another question, post another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason that in the first problem, you can divide is because each single case in the $10!$ original arrangements is

1. Equal probability
2. With a precisely equal distribution into equivalent cases
3. Where you actually want the count of the equivalent case-classes.

The problem with 4. in the second problem is not all of these cases have the same probability. It is far more difficult for all of the 3 identical balls to end up in P, for example.

There is no need to go about dividing the number of total arrangements. 2. does more than well enough in *actually* counting the different number of ways the objects can be distributed.

To do so, simply note that as a partition, choosing the objects for P completely determine the objects for Q (everything else). So:

1. If P has 3 identical, there is precisely $\binom{7}{0}=1$ case
2. If P has 2 identical, then you are choosing 1 of the other 7 non-identical objects, so precisely $\binom{7}{1}$ cases.
3. If P has 1 identical, choose 2 of the other 7, for $\binom{7}{2}$ cases.
4. If P has 0 identical, you choose $\binom{7}{3}$ ways.

The sum of these is the answer, without reference to the 10 total objects.

Comment: So you are not starting by arranging the 10 objects first ? Then from where exactly are you `choosing` $7 \choose 0$ or $7 \choose 1$ and so on ? Is it from the un arranged Row 1 ( full of objects ) ? Or are you choosing any blank space in Q and wanting to fill it by an identical ball ?

Comment: Yes, a completely unarranged row full of objects. There's no use considering the orderings of that row. That analogy is *only* useful for question 1.

Comment: why is it not useful in question two but in question 1 . That was the only way i could count for the order ( or different identities) of the object and then later take the order inside each individual boxes out .( first put in order and then take out order).

Comment: okay lets consider Case 2 . P has 2 identical . so in Q you are choosing 7C1 but that means you are only taking the fact that there is 1 identical ball in Q , but are you takng that fact that other than that one ball , all the other balls in Q can interchange with the balls in P to make a different case ? ( i believe you are taking but i cant understand how . choosing only means choosing for the 1 , what about the others ? like if the balls are AAABCDEFGH then when Q={ABCDEFG} are you taking the fact that it could also be Q={ABCDEF*H*} ?)

Comment: Because, as in the answer, the act of dividing **only** works if you have exactly equal probabilities. Specifically, if you were to randomly select 3 objects from the 10, the probability of getting the 3 identicals in P (one specific way) is $3!/10!$, but the probability you get 2 copies of the identical and one specific non-identical (another specific way you're counting) is $3\cdot2\cdot\binom{3}{1}/10!$.

Comment: About the Probablity *P* , the no. of ways to pick three same cards is only 1 . THe total no. of ways to pick 3 cards out of 10 is 10C3/3! or is it 10C3 ? but neither of them give your answer which is 3!/10! ( i mean if you were to find the probablity using my aswers we would get  $ 3!*3!*7!/10!$ and $3!*7!/10!$ as the probablities ,)what am i getting wrong .

Answer (score 0):

If we think of finding the numbers of each Case , step by step , Then there are 3 steps

1. In how man no. of ways does a different ball ( $D_1,D_2,D_3...D_7$ ) come into P ( if at all)
2. How arrangements in P matter
3. How arrangements in Q matter

Now we have to go through each of these steps for all four cases .

So for

Case 1:

Step 1: P has 0 identical balls . No of ways in which Different balls can come into P is $7 \choose 3 $

Step 2: Arrangments in P dont matter so whatever they may be ,they will count as 1.

Step 3: Arrangements in Q dont matter , so we will count this as 1

Hence no of ways for case 1 = ${7 \choose 3} \times 1 \times 1$

Similarly for Case 2: ${7 \choose 2} \times 1 \times 1$

and for Case 3 and 4 : ${7 \choose 1} \times 1 \times 1$ and ${7 \choose 0} \times 1 \times 1$

and on adding them we get the answer $$A= {7 \choose 3}+{7 \choose 2}+{7 \choose 1}+{7 \choose 0}$$

But we can write A differently $$A={7 \choose 4}+{7 \choose 5}+{7 \choose 6}+{7 \choose 7}$$
Hence 
$$A+A={7 \choose 3}+{7 \choose 2}+{7 \choose 1}+{7 \choose 0}+{7 \choose 4}+{7 \choose 5}+{7 \choose 6}+{7 \choose 7}=2^7$$ 
Which is $2^7$ 
so $2A=2^7$ and therefore $A=2^6$ and this is the answer.